# Is Entity Framework more mockable than Linq2Sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, interface, mocking, rhino-mocks

I've found that Linq2Sql doesn't (Rhino) mock well, as the interfaces I need aren't there.  Does EF generate code that's more mockable?

NOTE: I'm not mocking, yet, without interfaces, the next reader of this question may not have my bias.

**EDIT:** VS2008 / 3.5 for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework 1.0 is mockable: http://blogs.msdn.com/diego/archive/2008/03/03/unit-testing-your-entity-framework-domain-classes.aspx

It's not pretty, but it's possible.  EF 4 is much improved over EF 1.0 in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that if, for example, you have [Data Access Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) (DAOs) over your Linq2SQL objects they can implement intefaces and therefore work well with RhinoMocks.

Comment: That's what I do.  I have a layer of domain objects that are fully mockable/testable with my application code/services.  Then I use AutoMapper to move the data between the domain objects and the Linq2SQL objects.